# Select from one table depending on second table without JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I can perfectly query seperately.

`table1` stores ranges:

```
SELECT range_id, range_from, range_to FROM table1;
```

`table2` stores IDs:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2 WHERE id BETWEEN <x> AND <y>;
```

I need a query that for each tuple (`range_id`, `from`, `to`) from `table1` selects the `MAX(id)` from `table2` such that `MAX(id)` is between from and to:

```
range_id    max(id)
--------    -------
foo         3
bar         17
snafu       823467
```

I don't see how to accomplish this, since there's nothing to JOIN here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  *
,       (
        select  max(t2.id)
        from    table2 t2
        where   t2.id between t1.range_from and t1.range_to
        ) as max_id_in_range
from    table1 t1
```

Comment: +1, didn't know that something like that could work. Unfortunately, my SQL server doesn't as well. For the second SELECT, it reports "Syntax error or reserved word." (It's an SQLCI server on a HP NonStop Mainframe). Is there yet another way?

Comment: Solved it for SQLCI: the trick was to mimic a FULL OUTER JOIN with "JOIN <table2> ON 1=1" and then group by range_from and range_to, selecting MAX(id). Since I like your solution more than my own (although yours doesn't work on goddam SQL/CI), I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT t1.range_id ,t2.MAX(id)
   FROM  table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON  t1.range_ID = t2.ID
    WHERE t2.id BETWEEN <x> AND <y>
```

Comment: From the question: "I don't see how to accomplish this, since **there's nothing to JOIN here.**" I don't think the `range_id` from `table1` and `id` from `table2` are related in any way.